# Optimal approach to implement specific data storage

Tags: java, sql, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have to implement specific solution.

To put it simply it is some kind of knowledge base. Which is some storage of **key words** and **information** (basically some sort of knowledge base).

any number of key words can be connected to "information" and same words may be connected to different information. Example:

```
+-------------------------+-------+
|        Key_words        | Data  |
+-------------------------+-------+
| word1 word2 word5       | data1 |
| word3 word2 word4 word6 | data2 |
| word3 word7 word8       | data3 |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

words may change, data also can change.
I'm not sure how to do this "in a good way".

either it will be

```
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
|                Storage                       |
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
| id(int) | key_words(varchar) | data(varchar) |
+---------+--------------------+---------------+
```

which would require either "like" queries for searching data or some full-text search (elasticsearch/lucene/database provided full text search) e.g.

```
select * from Storage where Key_words like '%word1%' and Key_words like '%word3%'
```

Other idea is to store data in many to many relationship:

```
+---------+---------------+
|         Datum           |
+---------+---------------+
| id(int) | data(varchar) |
+---------+---------------+
| 1       |   data1       |
+---------+---------------+

+---------+------------------+
|         Keywords           |
+---------+------------------+
| id(int) | keyword(varchar) |
+---------+------------------+
| 1       | word1            |
| 2       | word2            |
| ...     | ...              |
| 5       | word5            |
| ...     | ...              |
+---------+------------------+

+---------+-----------------+--------------+
|             KwToData                     |
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
| id(int) | keyword_id(int) | data_id(int) |
| 1       | 1               | 1            |
| 2       | 2               | 1            |
| 3       | 2               | 2            |
| ...     | ...             |              |
| 5       | 5               | 1            |
| ...     | ...             |              |
+---------+-----------------+--------------+
```

but in this case I'll have to search for **articles** (keyword array + associated data) via nested search and updating/deleting keywords will be a bit tricky (delete - remove record from kw_to_data, update - search for keyword, if exists - add record to kw_to_data, if not - also add keyword to "Keywords" table)

Has someone done something similar, and if so, what is the best way to do this from your experience?

Comment: Your second form is the normalized form of the data and the structure usually recommended for relational databases.  The first form -- as strings -- is definitely not recommended.  In some databases, arrays, JSON, XML, or nested tables are also viable solutions.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly what specific data you're storing, but based on your question I'd say you should be looking for 3rd party solutions (elasticsearch etc.). Reimplementing the wheel is just wasted time.